# form validation is running when i am doing false but when i m removing false data is not inserting in ANGULARjs AND CODEIGNITER3

Tags: html, angularjs, codeigniter-3

textpublic function addUser()
{
$this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'Name', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('conpassword', 'Password Confirmation', 'required|matches\        [password]');

```
    $response = array(
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => 'Validation Error',
        'errors' => array()
    );

    if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE) {
        $response['errors'] = $this->form_validation->error_array();
       
    } else {
        
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

        $firstname = $data['firstname']; 
        $email = $data['email'];
        $password = $data['password'];

        $userData = array(
            'firstname' => $firstname,
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => hash('md5', $password)
        );

        $insert_id = $this->Data->addUser($userData);

        if ($insert_id) {
            $response['status'] = 'success';
            $response['message'] = 'Register Successfully';
            $response['response_data'] = $userData;
        } else {
            $response['message'] = 'Failed to register';
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

THIS IS HTML CODE WITH JS

```
Registration or Sign Up form in HTML CSS | CodingLab
"\>






    <h2>Registration</h2>
    
        
        
            First-Name<br>
            
        <br>

        <small class="form-text f-14 text-left vi-red-clr" ng-bind-html="trustedHtml(errors.email)">        </small>
        <div class="input-box">
            <label for="">Email</label><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" ng-model="email" name="email">
        </div><br>

        <small class="form-text f-14 text-left vi-red-clr" ng-bind-html="trustedHtml(errors.password)"></small>
        <div class="input-box">
            <label for="">Password</label><br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Create password" ng-model="password" name="password">
        </div><br>

        <small class="form-text f-14 text-left vi-red-clr" ng-bind-html="trustedHtml(errors.conpassword)"></small>
        <div class="input-box">
            <label for="">Confirm-Password</label><br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm password" ng-model="conpassword" name="conpassword">
        </div><br>

        <div class="input-box button">
            <input type="button" value="Register Now" name="btnInsert" ng-click="insertData()">
        </div>

        <div class="text">
            <h3>Already have an account? <a href="http://localhost/SIGNUP/Register/login">Login now</a></h3>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

var $config = {
    'base_url': '<?php echo $this->config->item("base_url") ?>'
}

app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$sce', function ($scope, $http, $sce) {

    $scope.trustedHtml = function(plainText) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(plainText);
        };
        $scope.errors = {};
        
    $scope.insertData = function () {
        var data = {
            'firstname': $scope.firstname,
            'email': $scope.email,
            'password': $scope.password,
            'conpassword': $scope.conpassword,
        };



        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: $config.base_url + 'Register/addUser',
            data: data,
        }).then(function(response) {
                    if (response.data.status === 'success') {
                        alert('Registration successful');
                    } else {
                        $scope.errors = response.data.errors;
                    }
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log('Error:', error);
                });
    }



}]);
```

I AM EXPECTING validation should be run when i am submitting without filling ant field and data should be inserting after filling all fields